# How to find whether the shortest path from s (any starting vertex) to v (any vertex) in the undirected graph is unique or not?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Given an undirected graph *G = (V, E)* with no negative weights.
What is the complexity for checking uniqueness of shortest path for every vertex in the given graph?

Answer (score 8):

You can easily modify shortest path algorithms to find number of shortest paths too. For instance consider this Dijkstra code:

```py
def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
    assert source in self.vertices
    dist = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
    previous = {vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices}
    dist[source] = 0
    q = self.vertices.copy()
    neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
    for start, end, cost in self.edges:
        neighbours[start].add((end, cost))

    while q:
        u = min(q, key=lambda vertex: dist[vertex])
        q.remove(u)
        if dist[u] == inf or u == dest:
            break
        for v, cost in neighbours[u]:
            alt = dist[u] + cost
            if alt < dist[v]:                                  # Relax (u,v,a)
                dist[v] = alt
                previous[v] = u
```

We add another list to store the number of shortest path to each node.

```
num_path = {vertex: 0 for vertex in self.vertices}
```

Then in the relaxing stage, instead of checking whether the new distance (`alt`) is less than previous distance, we check if it is equal too. If it is equal we increment the number of shortest paths for that node:

```
if alt == dist[v]:
    num_path[v] += 1
```

When we find a new shortest for a node, the number of shortest path for the new node is equal to the number of shortest path of its parent:

```
if alt < distance:
    num_path[v] = num_path[u]
    ...
```

So in the end if `num_path[v]==1` then we can conclude that there is a unique shortest path from `source` to `v`.

Here is the final code:

```py
def dijkstra(self, source, dest):
    assert source in self.vertices
    dist = {vertex: inf for vertex in self.vertices}
    previous = {vertex: None for vertex in self.vertices}
    num_path = {vertex: 0 for vertex in self.vertices}
    dist[source] = 0
    num_path[source] = 1
    q = self.vertices.copy()
    neighbours = {vertex: set() for vertex in self.vertices}
    for start, end, cost in self.edges:
        neighbours[start].add((end, cost))

    while q:
        u = min(q, key=lambda vertex: dist[vertex])
        q.remove(u)
        if dist[u] == inf or u == dest:
            break
        for v, cost in neighbours[u]:
            alt = dist[u] + cost
            if alt < dist[v]:                                  # Relax (u,v,a)
                dist[v] = alt
                previous[v] = u
                num_path[v] = num_path[u]
            elif alt == dist[v]:
                num_path[v] += 1
```

So the complexity will be equal to the complexity of your shortest path algorithm.

Comment: `elif alt == dist[v]:`
`num_path[v] += num_path[u]`
If we find a path from a vertex to its neighbour which is equal to the estimated shortest path distance, then number of shortest paths would be number of shortest paths of the vertex + number of shortest paths of the neighbour